# Unable to drop schema in derby

Tags: java, database, derby

Here as you can see I have a schema with name **MySchema**

[image: MySchema database]

But now I wanted to delete it
[image: Dropping schema]

But it is not working and showing me the error saying "Encountered EOF" :
[image]

How could I delete this schema?

*Using java-8, netbeans-8, and execution was being made using Client driver i.e. org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the restrict keyword to the end of your command, e.g.

```
drop schema myschema restrict;
```

This enforces the rule that no objects can be defined in the schema when it is to be deleted.

Comment: Please give me some reference from where I could read about derby database with java's driver.

Comment: You can read about Derby in the development guide at: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/

Comment: Specifically, info about the drop schema command is at: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj31648.html